# Is there an Alternative for event.getParams().keyCode?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I was able to use this with `ui:inputText` but can't use it with `lightning:input`. Is there an alternative? I can't change the `lightning:input` to `ui:inputText` because I would need to update most of my code if I do that.

```
event.getParams().keyCode
```

Any alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `event.getParams().keyCode`, despite [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BP92IAG). The traditional `event.keyCode` work as you'd expect.

Demo:

```
<aura:application >
    <div onkeydown="{!c.keypress}" >
        <lightning:input label="Label"/>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    keypress: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
    }
})
```

---

If by some reason it's not working the way you expect, something else is likely going on.